# CodeIgniter Cart and Session lost when refresh page

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, shopping-cart, cart

I'm using CodeIgniter v2.1.3 and having a problem with using CI Cart and Session. When I insert an element into Cart, everything gone fine. But when I refresh the page, all saved Cart items disappeared. The same problem happened when I use Session Class.

But everything works well on my localhost. The problem just happends on my Server.

There are some websites on my Server now and they dont have any problem with Session. So I guess it must be caused by CI.

Here is Session configuarations in application/config/config.php :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'blowup_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions1';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I tried to print the session_id but it returned nothing. So I guess the Session class did not generate any session_id. Try to start the session manually by using session_start(), the session_id was generated.

I also tried to save something by using $_SESSION, and they are saved without any problem.

Does it mean that the CI_Session and Cart library were not auto loaded?

How could I fix it? Or is there any Session class could replace the current one?

PS: My Server is running CentOS 5, PHP v 5.2.17 , Apache 2.2.23 and MySQL 5.0.96

**UPDATED**

Below is the function I use in Controller to add an item into Cart. The data ($params) is posted via an AJAX request (using jquery AJAX). The returned data is a HTML view.

```
public function add_to_cart(){
        $this->layout->set_template('ajax');
        if ($this->is_post()){
            $params = $this->get_all_post_data();
            //Debug::dump($this->cart);die;
            if (isset($params['id']) && (int)$params['id']>0){
                $product = $this->_product_model->get_record_by_id((int)$params['id']);
                if (!is_null($product)){
                    if (count($this->cart->contents())>0){
                        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
                            if ($item['id']==$product->id){
                                $data = array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],'qty'=>++$item['qty']);
                                $this->cart->update($data);
                            }else{
                                $data = array('id'=>$product->id,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product->price,'name'=>$product->id,'options'=>array('image'=>$product->thumb,'product_name'=>$product->title));
                                $this->cart->insert($data);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        $data = array('id'=>$product->id,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product->price,'name'=>$product->id,'options'=>array('image'=>$product->thumb,'product_name'=>$product->title));
                        $this->cart->insert($data);
                    }
                    $this->session->set_userdata(array('test'=>'Session test'));

                    $this->layout->load('cart/topmenu_cart', $this->data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have your tried renaming the session cookie name , removing the underscore?

Comment: @tomexsans : I did it but had no luck

Comment: how are you using the cart? might want to post you're code here

Comment: @Gian U : Yep. The problem is : CI is using "Cookie" to store the data, and the Cookie size is limited at 4KB while my need-to-save data is larger than that size. I decided to use Native Session to save the data. You can search "Native Session" for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to use database to store session data instead? Based on your settings, I guess because your data is to large to hold in a 4KB cookie.